# How to get stripe subscription current_period_end as date

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

My end goal is to check `subscription.cancel_at_period_end` for `false` and store subscription end date as a moment date object.

```
const subscriptionEndDate = moment(subscription.current_period_end);
```

This is the result field coming from stripe in test mode.

```
current_period_end: 1649650039
```

But even using `new Date(subscription.current_period_end)` is coming back as `1970-01-20T02:14:10.039Z`

Is this not the field that is suppose to show when the next billing date is ?

Any thoughts? What am I missing ?

UPDATE:

I was just doing some testing and figured out if I multiply that value by **1000** it comes out to be **1649650039000** which equates to

> Mon 11 April 2022 00:07:19

Is there a reason for this? Is this a safe method moving forward?

UPDATE:

I accepted answer below and am providing momentjs that converts directly to unix timestamp.

```
const date = moment(new Date()).unix();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Issue

- Stripe reports date fields as [Unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  These represent a date/time as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 (kinda...leap seconds are weird).
- The [Javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) attempts to convert the number of *milliseconds* since January 1, 1970 as that is an increment of time that is more relevant to front-end web coding.

### Solution

You have already discovered an adequate solution, that is multiply the timestamp by 1000 and thereby convert the value in seconds to a value in milliseconds.  This appears to be a common work around [1](https://electrictoolbox.com/unix-timestamp-javascript/), [2](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-get-timestamp-javascript/), [3](https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-date-in-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming from your answer, I can safely use this method.

Comment: Yeah, that works